# How are migrated questions to askubuntu treated when are actually off topic?

Tags: support, status-completed, asking-questions, migration

Stumbling upon [this migrated question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274470/ssh-intermittent-blocking-connections), I noticed that it asks about a problem in an EoL version (12.04). It even has a bounty set on it.

Now I do know that in some cases when the question is not a version-specific question and also applies to non-EoL versions, they choice is not to close them. Was this the case with the given question?

Comment: I would VTC that post but the bounty, set by OP, prevents it (a ridiculous system IMO as a bounty does not make a question on topic but that is another debate) and no one can close it until the bounty expires. IMO if the OP didn't bounty this it would be closed, though I could be missing something.

Comment: Seems that the answer is we should post on meta about them (thank you!), or flag for mod attention. FYI, it seems that migrated questions can't be migrated onwards, but I flagged the question after it was returned to Stack Overflow, and it was migrated to [unix.se] where as far as I know it's on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderators are more than capable of handling questions in this case.

This question was migrated and before VTCers came by and addressed it, the bounty was posted.  To that end, the bounty was removed and the question force-closed by moderator diamond, therefore the 'migration' on SO's side will show up as "rejected".